# When I run my jar file, it doesn't work because it can't find books.csv, but it exists at the specified source

Tags: java, csv, file, jar, java.util.scanner

My jar file won't run. It gives an error in reference to a file that is in the main package.

java -jar IA.jar

```
file not found
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/books.csv (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:158)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:641)
    at main.Library.loadScanner(Library.java:98)
    at main.Library.loadBooks(Library.java:119)
    at main.Library.<init>(Library.java:25)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Scanner.hasNext()" because "scanner" is null
    at main.Library.loadScanner(Library.java:107)
    at main.Library.loadBooks(Library.java:119)
    at main.Library.<init>(Library.java:25)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

The main class looks like this:

```
public class Main {
    private final static String root = "src/main/";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] dirs = {root + "books.csv", root + "teacher.csv", root + "users.csv"};
        Library library = new Library(dirs); // libary instance

        new HomePage(library); // open GUI
    }
}
```

The library method loadScanner() is used to open the .csv files which act as a sort of dummy database.

```
private ArrayList<String[]> loadScanner(String dir) {
        File myFile1 = new File(dir);
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(myFile1);
            scanner.useDelimiter(",");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("file not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {

            String line = scanner.next();

            String[] r = line.trim().split(",");
            data.add(r);
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: What's the code?

Comment: @Erwin ```public class Main {
    private final static String root = "src/main/";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] dirs = {root + "books.csv", root + "teacher.csv", root + "users.csv"};
        Library library = new Library(dirs); // libary instance

        new HomePage(library); // open GUI
    }
}```

Comment: put it in the question, I can't see it like this

Comment: what is the line that caused the error? `at main.Library.loadScanner(Library.java:98)`

Comment: At runtime you do not have a src/main folder. Use Class.getRessource() to load the file, if it is in the classpath

Comment: @Jens How do I fix that?

Comment: @Jens I am unfamiliar with Class.getResource(). How would I use it in my main class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a resource file from within jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar)

Comment: @Edwin Ryerson, First decide what you want to achieve? (a) Jar reads a book.csv file placed in a certain directory (b) Jar reads a book.csv file placed in the same directory as Jar (c ) Jar reads a book.csv file inside the Jar.